# Can not get the output of web service

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-asynctask

I have a class designed to access my web service methods. the problem is when I'm trying to access the output of my web service method in an Async call, It's empty. what should I do?
This is my web service class:

```
package ClassLibrary;

public class WebService {
    private String namespace="";
    private String url="";

    public WebService(String namespace,String url) {
        super();
        this.namespace = namespace;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String CallMethod(String methodName,PropertyInfo pi) {
        String result = "default";
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespace, methodName);
        request.addProperty(pi);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(namespace+methodName, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            result= response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

and this is how I'm trying to call web service:

```
private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private Activity activity;
    public String wsOutput="";
    public String methodName="";
    private WebService ws;

    public AsyncCallWS(Activity activity,String methodName) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        this.methodName = methodName;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        ws = new WebService(PublicVariable.NAMESPACE, PublicVariable.URL);
        PropertyInfo pi= new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("UserID");
        pi.setValue("1");
        pi.setType(String.class);
        wsOutput=ws.CallMethod("GetPersonalInfo", pi);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (methodName == "GetPersonalInfo") {
            Log.d("Ehsan","OUTPUT IS:"+ wsOutput);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:

- Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
- Progress, the type of the progress units published during the background computation.
- Result, the type of the result of the background computation.

**onPostExecute(Result)** is invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. The result of the background computation is passed to this step as a parameter and you are not passing the resulting value.

```
private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private Activity activity;
    public String methodName="";
    private WebService ws;

    public AsyncCallWS(Activity activity,String methodName) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        this.methodName = methodName;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        ws = new WebService(PublicVariable.NAMESPACE, PublicVariable.URL);
        PropertyInfo pi= new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("UserID");
        pi.setValue("1");
        pi.setType(String.class);

        String wsOutput = ws.CallMethod("GetPersonalInfo", pi);

        return wsOutput;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }

        Log.d("Ehsan","OUTPUT IS:"+ result);
    }
}
```